# cartographerをcatkin buildしようとするとエラーが出る．

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

ros noeticでSLAMをするためにcartographerを使用したかったのでコンパイルを行ったが下記のようなエラーが出る．

```
## ubuntu@ubuntu:~/ros1_ws$ catkin build

## Profile: default
Extending: [cached] /opt/ros/noetic:/home/ubuntu/ydlidar_ros2_ws/install/ydlidar_ros2_driver
Workspace: /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws

## Build Space: [exists] /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/build
Devel Space: [exists] /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/devel
Install Space: [unused] /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/install
Log Space: [exists] /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/logs
Source Space: [exists] /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src
DESTDIR: [unused] None

## Devel Space Layout: linked
Install Space Layout: None

## Additional CMake Args: None
Additional Make Args: None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server: True
Cache Job Environments: False

## Buildlisted Packages: None
Skiplisted Packages: None

## Workspace configuration appears valid.

[build] Found 4 packages in 0.0 seconds.

[build] Package table is up to date.

Starting  >>> cartographer

Starting  >>> cartographer_ros_msgs

Finished  <<< cartographer_ros_msgs                [ 7.4 seconds ]

Finished  <<< cartographer                         [ 28.5 seconds ]

Starting  >>> cartographer_ros

---

Errors     << cartographer_ros:make /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/logs/cartographer_ros/build.make.001.log
In file included from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/ros_map_writing_points_processor.h:25,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:37:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/devel/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:68:7: error: redefinition of ‘class cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D’
68 | class ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D : public ::google::protobuf::Message /* @@protoc_insertion_point(class_definition:cartographer.mapping.proto.ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D) */ {
|       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/range_data_inserter_options.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/submaps_options_2d.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/local_trajectory_builder_options_2d.pb.h:35,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/trajectory_builder_options.pb.h:35,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.h:23,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:17:
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:68:7: note: previous definition of ‘class cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D’
68 | class ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D : public ::google::protobuf::Message /* @@protoc_insertion_point(class_definition:cartographer.mapping.proto.ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D) */ {
|       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/ros_map_writing_points_processor.h:25,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:37:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/devel/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:195:13: error: redefinition of ‘void cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::clear_hit_probability()’
195 | inline void ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::clear_hit_probability() {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/range_data_inserter_options.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/submaps_options_2d.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/local_trajectory_builder_options_2d.pb.h:35,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/trajectory_builder_options.pb.h:35,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.h:23,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:17:
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:195:13: note: ‘void cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::clear_hit_probability()’ previously defined here
195 | inline void ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::clear_hit_probability() {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/ros_map_writing_points_processor.h:25,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:37:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/devel/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:198:15: error: redefinition of ‘double cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::hit_probability() const’
198 | inline double ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::hit_probability() const {
|               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/range_data_inserter_options.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/submaps_options_2d.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/local_trajectory_builder_options_2d.pb.h:35,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/trajectory_builder_options.pb.h:35,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.h:23,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:17:
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:198:15: note: ‘double cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::hit_probability() const’ previously defined here
198 | inline double ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::hit_probability() const {
|               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/ros_map_writing_points_processor.h:25,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:37:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/devel/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:202:13: error: redefinition of ‘void cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::set_hit_probability(double)’
202 | inline void ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::set_hit_probability(double value) {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/range_data_inserter_options.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/submaps_options_2d.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/local_trajectory_builder_options_2d.pb.h:35,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/trajectory_builder_options.pb.h:35,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.h:23,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:17:
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:202:13: note: ‘void cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::set_hit_probability(double)’ previously defined here
202 | inline void ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::set_hit_probability(double value) {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/ros_map_writing_points_processor.h:25,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:37:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/devel/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:209:13: error: redefinition of ‘void cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::clear_miss_probability()’
209 | inline void ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::clear_miss_probability() {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/range_data_inserter_options.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/submaps_options_2d.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/local_trajectory_builder_options_2d.pb.h:35,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/trajectory_builder_options.pb.h:35,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.h:23,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:17:
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:209:13: note: ‘void cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::clear_miss_probability()’ previously defined here
209 | inline void ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::clear_miss_probability() {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/ros_map_writing_points_processor.h:25,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:37:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/devel/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:212:15: error: redefinition of ‘double cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::miss_probability() const’
212 | inline double ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::miss_probability() const {
|               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/range_data_inserter_options.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/submaps_options_2d.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/local_trajectory_builder_options_2d.pb.h:35,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/trajectory_builder_options.pb.h:35,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.h:23,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:17:
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:212:15: note: ‘double cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::miss_probability() const’ previously defined here
212 | inline double ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::miss_probability() const {
|               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/ros_map_writing_points_processor.h:25,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:37:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/devel/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:216:13: error: redefinition of ‘void cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::set_miss_probability(double)’
216 | inline void ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::set_miss_probability(double value) {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/range_data_inserter_options.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/submaps_options_2d.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/local_trajectory_builder_options_2d.pb.h:35,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/trajectory_builder_options.pb.h:35,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.h:23,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:17:
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:216:13: note: ‘void cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::set_miss_probability(double)’ previously defined here
216 | inline void ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::set_miss_probability(double value) {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/ros_map_writing_points_processor.h:25,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:37:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/devel/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:223:13: error: redefinition of ‘void cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::clear_insert_free_space()’
223 | inline void ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::clear_insert_free_space() {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/range_data_inserter_options.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/submaps_options_2d.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/local_trajectory_builder_options_2d.pb.h:35,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/trajectory_builder_options.pb.h:35,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.h:23,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:17:
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:223:13: note: ‘void cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::clear_insert_free_space()’ previously defined here
223 | inline void ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::clear_insert_free_space() {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/ros_map_writing_points_processor.h:25,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:37:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/devel/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:226:13: error: redefinition of ‘bool cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::insert_free_space() const’
226 | inline bool ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::insert_free_space() const {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/range_data_inserter_options.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/submaps_options_2d.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/local_trajectory_builder_options_2d.pb.h:35,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/trajectory_builder_options.pb.h:35,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.h:23,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:17:
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:226:13: note: ‘bool cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::insert_free_space() const’ previously defined here
226 | inline bool ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::insert_free_space() const {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/ros_map_writing_points_processor.h:25,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:37:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/devel/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:230:13: error: redefinition of ‘void cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::set_insert_free_space(bool)’
230 | inline void ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::set_insert_free_space(bool value) {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/range_data_inserter_options.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/submaps_options_2d.pb.h:34,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/local_trajectory_builder_options_2d.pb.h:35,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/trajectory_builder_options.pb.h:35,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.h:23,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/assets_writer.cc:17:
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/mapping/proto/2d/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h:230:13: note: ‘void cartographer::mapping::proto::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::set_insert_free_space(bool)’ previously defined here
230 | inline void ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserterOptions2D::set_insert_free_space(bool value) {
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.h:31,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.cc:17:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/map_builder_bridge.h:94:57: error: ‘TrajectoryState’ is not a member of ‘cartographer::mapping::PoseGraphInterface’
94 |            ::cartographer::mapping::PoseGraphInterface::TrajectoryState>
|                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/map_builder_bridge.h:94:57: error: ‘TrajectoryState’ is not a member of ‘cartographer::mapping::PoseGraphInterface’
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/map_builder_bridge.h:94:72: error: template argument 2 is invalid
94 |            ::cartographer::mapping::PoseGraphInterface::TrajectoryState>
|                                                                        ^
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/map_builder_bridge.h:94:72: error: template argument 4 is invalid
In file included from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.cc:17:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.h:176:54: error: ‘TrajectoryState’ is not a member of ‘cartographer::mapping::PoseGraphInterface’
176 |           cartographer::mapping::PoseGraphInterface::TrajectoryState>&
|                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.h:176:54: error: ‘TrajectoryState’ is not a member of ‘cartographer::mapping::PoseGraphInterface’
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.h:176:69: error: template argument 1 is invalid
176 |           cartographer::mapping::PoseGraphInterface::TrajectoryState>&
|                                                                     ^
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.h:176:69: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.h:176:69: error: template argument 3 is invalid
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.cc:57:50: error: ‘TrajectoryState’ in ‘class cartographer::mapping::PoseGraphInterface’ does not name a type
57 |     ::cartographer::mapping::PoseGraphInterface::TrajectoryState;
|                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.cc:77:43: error: ‘TrajectoryState’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘TrajectoryOptions’?
77 | std::string TrajectoryStateToString(const TrajectoryState trajectory_state) {
|                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                                           TrajectoryOptions
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.cc: In function ‘std::string cartographer_ros::{anonymous}::TrajectoryStateToString(int)’:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.cc:79:10: error: ‘TrajectoryState’ has not been declared
79 |     case TrajectoryState::ACTIVE:
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.cc:81:10: error: ‘TrajectoryState’ has not been declared
81 |     case TrajectoryState::FINISHED:
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.cc:83:10: error: ‘TrajectoryState’ has not been declared
83 |     case TrajectoryState::FROZEN:
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.cc:85:10: error: ‘TrajectoryState’ has not been declared
85 |     case TrajectoryState::DELETED:
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.cc: In constructor ‘cartographer_ros::Node::Node(const cartographer_ros::NodeOptions&, std::unique_ptrcartographer::mapping::MapBuilderInterface, tf2_ros::Buffer*, bool)’:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.cc:98:75: error: no matching function for call to ‘tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster::TransformBroadcaster()’
98 |       map_builder_bridge_(node_options_, std::move(map_builder), tf_buffer) {
|                                                                           ^
In file included from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.h:52,
from /home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.cc:17:
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h:53:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class NodeT, class AllocatorT> tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster::TransformBroadcaster(NodeT&&, const rclcpp::QoS&, const rclcpp::PublisherOptionsWithAllocator<AllocatorT>&)’
53 |   TransformBroadcaster(
|   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h:53:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/ubuntu/ros1_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/node.cc:98:75: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
98 |       map_builder_bridge_(node_options_, std::move(map_builder), tf_buffer) {
|                                                                           ^

中略
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:457,
from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Geometry:11,
from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/urdfdom_headers/cmake/../../../../include/cartographer/io/submap_painter.h:20,
from /h~~

.................................................................................................
Failed     << cartographer_ros:make                [ Exited with code 2 ]

Failed    <<< cartographer_ros                     [ 1 minute and 9.0 seconds ]

Abandoned <<< cartographer_rviz                    [ Unrelated job failed ]

[build] Summary: 2 of 4 packages succeeded.

[build]   Ignored:   None.

[build]   Warnings:  None.

[build]   Abandoned: 1 packages were abandoned.

[build]   Failed:    1 packages failed.

[build] Runtime: 1 minute and 37.7 seconds total.
```

環境
raspberry pi 4 model B 8GB
Ubuntu 20.04 server (20.04)をdesktop化
ROS (Noetic)
で行っています．

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 を使用しているようですが、システム要件では Ubuntu **22.04** となっています。

> #### [System requirements](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#system-requirements)
>
> The current Debian-based target platforms for Rolling Ridley are:
>
> - Tier 1: Ubuntu Linux - Jammy (22.04) 64-bit
> - Tier 3: Debian Linux - Bullseye (11) 64-bit